# How to disable OUTPUT console in vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am using vscode on Mac and my `OUTPUT` console keeps popping up with random errors. I would like to know how I can just `ignore` this?

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: jsx. Error is coming from styled-jsx language